# Obtaining pivot table data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a Users Model and within it I have the following relationship

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('user_id', 'group_id');
}
```

I have also set the inverse within the Group model.  When complete, I have a users_user_group table with data like so

```
+------+-------------------+----------+
| id   |           user_id | group_id |
+------+-------------------+----------+
|  755 |                 1 |        1 |
|  756 |                 1 |        2 |
|  757 |                 1 |        3 |
|  758 |                 1 |        4 |
|  759 |                 1 |        5 |
|  760 |                 1 |        6 |
|  761 |                 1 |        7 |
|  762 |                 1 |        8 |
|  763 |                 1 |        9 |
|  764 |                 1 |       10 |
|  765 |                 2 |       11 |
|  766 |                 2 |        7 |
|  767 |                 2 |       10 |
|  768 |                 3 |       12 |
|  769 |                 3 |       13 |
```

So I know the data is being inserted properly.  Now within one of my controllers, I am trying to get all users who are part of the admin group, which has the group_id of 1.  So I am doing
$users = User::where('active', '=', true)->get();

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if($user->group()->where('groupName', 'admin')) {
        $groupArray[] = $user;
    }
}
```

For some reason though, every user is added to this array, where only the admins should be added.

I was just looking for advice as to what I am doing wrong?  Do I need to link the groupName to the groupId somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userGroups = $user->group()->where('groupName', 'admin')->get();

    if( $userGroups->count() ) {
        $groupArray[] = $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the base of your requirement to get all user related to specific Group

You can do something like

```
$users = User::whereHas('group', function($q) use($group_id){
    $q->where('group.id', '>=', $group_id);
})->get();
```

or with Eager Loading:

```
$users = User::where('id', $user_id)
  ->with([ 'group' => function($query) use ($group_id) {
    $query->where('id', $group_id)
}]);
```

Comment: The first suggestion gives me Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, integer given.  Also, what happens if I dont know the groupId, only the groupName?  Thanks

Comment: `group_id` its just the condition you want to apply on group.